# Manually Upgrade Extension

Tags: extension

I wanted to upgrade my Mosaico extension to the latest version. There was no upgrade link on the extensions screen so I downloaded the latest release and replaced the source files. However, the version number is still corresponding to the previous files. Do I need to do anything else to notify Civi that the files have been updated? I know in Drupal you would normally run the database update, but I don't know if there is something similar in CiviCRM? I couldn't find any documentation on a manual upgrade process.

I am running CiviCRM version 4.7.28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to uninstall the previous version first and then to install the new version - just replacing the files will not do anything.

So, Please replace your previous version of extension in the extension folder - and uninstall it first.

Then do replace your new extension and install the same - that should work as you excepted

Ref: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/

I guess this helps !!!!

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I realised I had actually downloaded a fork of the extension repository by mistake, so there wasn't actually a newer version!